# remove effect is not working after adding a new li to group of li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created some sortable li using jquery.ui and also there is an add button to append new li in the end with this there is an remove text inside every li on whose click the parent li is removed but this remove functionality is not working good with newly created li or rather i should say the click action on remove text is not working on newly added li for more explanation i have added.
[for working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Abhimanue/8fXWw/)

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


        $(".btn").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldsCount = $(".remove").length;
            if(fieldsCount){
                number = $('ul#sortable li:last').attr("id");
                number++;
                $("#sortable").append('<li id ="'+number+'" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item '+number+' <a class="remove hello'+number+'">remove</a></li>');
                        $("#sortable").sortable('refresh');
                }else{
                    $("#sortable").append('<li id="1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1 <a class="remove hello1">remove</a></li>');
                    $("#sortable").sortable('refresh');
                }

        });
        $("a.remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Wow... whole description in one sentence with exactly one  punctuation mark! Hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.click()`, try `.on()` in its delegated event mode:

```
    $("#sortable").on("click", "a.remove", function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

When you use `.click()` it only binds a handler to elements that exist *at that moment,* and so doesn't automatically work on elements added later. Using the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on) allows you to bind the handler to a parent that already exists, but in the second parameter you can supply a selector to match the elements you really care about - these element do *not* need to exist yet at the time you call `.on()`. For a more detailed explanation read [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8fXWw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Click event will not work on dynamically added elements. You should use jQuery.on to bind click event to the dynamically added LIs. Something like this:

```
$("#sortable").on("click", "a.remove", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```